# PackageStats data returning 0 in Android JB

Tags: android

I am  working on custom Application Manager and try to get the disk usage of 
installed package.

So `PackageManager.getpackageSizeInfo` was removed from SDK on 0.9->1.0
update

```
android.content.pm.PackageStats(String pkgName)  (cacheSize, codeSize, 
dataSize) returns always "0"
```

Has anybody any solution to get the total disc space used by an 
installed package?

This is the code:

```
public long getTotalExternalSize(PackageStats ps) {
    if (ps != null) {
        System.out.println("--Uday-- Entering inside the ps! = null condition for  getTotalExternalSize!!! " + ps.codeSize +" " + ps.dataSize
                + " " + ps.cacheSize +" and packagename is " + ps.packageName );
        return ps.externalCodeSize + ps.externalDataSize
                + ps.externalMediaSize + ps.externalObbSize;
    }
    System.out.println("--Uday-- Not entering inside the ps! = null condition for getTotalExternalSize!!!");
    return SIZE_INVALID;
}
```